# design pattern which allow different return type

Tags: design-patterns

I have a class which have certain functionality and return type is "A" (just an assumption)
I need to create few class which will just use the data "A", making some customization and return it in different format. (Say, classB return "Type B" and class C return "Type C".
Both the Type B and Type C is using same data "A" but with few customization and few added data.

I analyzed builder, adapter, strategy and factory pattern. But all are returning either void or same data type or interface. I want my return type to be different.

Please guide me which design pattern i can use in this case.

Regards,
Saurabh

Comment: Patterns emerge from the code. You rarely choose them in advance. And you probably don't want a pattern, but probably use a generic type, if your language supports that. Tell us which language you're using. It's also unclear how you plan on using classes B and C. Why should they be part of any pattern? Why can't they just be completely different classes doing something different with an A? Be more concrete. Tell your language, and tell what you want to achieve, precisely

Comment: return types are for class methods and not for classes itself  so you might like to revise the language of your question a bit to have more clarity on requirement. Also, is there any relation among these return types ?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that there will be a method inside the class. Below is bit more explaination.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that there will be a method inside the class. Below is bit more explanation......

Web API- Class A- Method M->return type (custom class B)........

Client - X- Consuming method M of Web API (This is working fine)......

Now I have few more client....

Client - Y- (need same data which is being returned by Web API- Class A- method B but in different format).........

In the same way, we have some more client who need same data but in different format.)

Comment: @Saurabh when you have similar data structures with slight variations in data only, you probably shouldn't try to use a behavioral design pattern. Just use composition or inheritance to share the common fields between data structures. Look for a design pattern when you have a family of classes with similar *behavior* and want to address a variation of behavior.